# How to revoke some company from accessing my google search console (GSC)?

Tags: google-search-console

I registered at some SEO helper company and give them access to my GSC to do some data audit.

However, the audit doesn't help and I don't want to share any data with them.

How can I revoke it?

Comment: What method did you use to grant them access?

Comment: It's just a Google popup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the left panel of Google Search Console, click **Settings**. Then click **Users and permissions**.

Revoke the company you gave access to.

Comment: If that is how you gave them access.  If you verified their account with file upload or meta tags, the solution will be different.

Comment: I can't find the company. Actually I didn't use uploading files or meta tags. I just clicked in a Google-domain popup. However, it's very weird that I can't find the company in the settings panel you mentioned.

Comment: @AGamePlayer It's _possible_ that you let them log in as you (a very shady practice).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 any idea about how to revoke that case?

Comment: @AGamePlayer You could log out everywhere. I'd recommend changing your password too, though. (Beware: unless you have proper 2FA set up, or remember stuff like when you created your account, you might lock yourself out of your Google account by signing out everywhere.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 thanks a lot. sounds decent way to resolve.

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions I found it at last. You can remove the access here. I just removed the *** seo helper company :)